# Horizontal UIStackView : Does value 999 or 1000 carry any special meaning in Horizontal Content Compression Resistance?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following 3 components within a Horizontal stack view.

1. Yellow `UILabel`
2. Red `UIImageView`
3. Green `UIImageView`

The distribution for the Horizontal stack view is **Fill**.

The content mode for `UIImageView` is **Aspect fit**. They are using SFSymbol named "pin.fill".

The number of line for `UILabel` is 0, so that it supports multilines.

All the 3 components are having same **Content Hugging Priority (250) and Content Compression Resistance Priority (750)**

### When Horizontal Content Compression Resistance for UILabel is 750 to 998

[image]

[image]

---

My questions are

1. Why the red `UIImage` take up most space, even though all 3 of them are having same **Content Hugging Priority (250) and Content Compression Resistance Priority (750)**?
2. My intention is letting yellow `UILabel` fill up most space. However, I can only achieve so, if I increase the **Horizontal Content Compression Resistance** (For `UILabel` only) up to 999 or 1000. I thought, as long as any value is higher than 750 will be good enough? Does 999 or 1000 value in Horizontal Content Compression Resistance carry any special meaning?

### When Horizontal Content Compression Resistance for UILabel is 999 or 1000

[image]

Please do take note that, even when Horizontal Content Compression Resistance for UILabel is 999 or 1000, both red & green `UIImageView`'s width will be compressed. But, they are compressed with different strength, which end up 2 `UIImageView` are having slightly different width. Why?

---

p/s

The complete project code is located at https://github.com/yccheok/stackoverflow/tree/master/66444344/test

Comment: Have you given your image views a width and/or height constraint? What Content Mode are they using - Aspect Fill? What size is the actual thumb-tack image?

Comment: The content mode for `UIImageView` is **Aspect fit**.

Comment: @DonMag I also post a complete project code for your reference purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-thinking things a bit.

What you want to do is tell the two image views to "hug" their content, and leave everything else at the default Hugging and Compression Resistance values.

So, Label properties:

[image]

Both "pin" image views:

[image]

It will look like this in your Storyboard:

[image]

Give this code a try... connect the label to the `@IBOutlet` and run the app. Each tap will cycle through 4 different length strings for the label:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    
    let strs: [String] = [
        "Very Short",
        "A little longer, but still one line.",
        "Button - You can set the title, image, and other appearance properties of a button.",
        "UIStackView - creates and manages the constraints necessary to create horizontal or vertical stacks of views. It will dynamically add and remove its constraints to react to views being removed or added to its stack. With customization it can also react and influence the layout around it.",
    ]
    
    var idx: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        label.text = strs[idx % strs.count]
        
        // tap anywhere in the view
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        idx += 1
        label.text = strs[idx % strs.count]
    }
    
}
```

and the result will be:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But, why do we have to place 1000 on "Content Hugging Priority" for every UIImageView? Why doesn't a relatively higher value like 300 work? Does 1000 has a special meaning?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - Priority of 1000 means **required**. While other values may work (quick experimentation appears to indicate >=760), there's no real reason ***not*** to set it to required, since that is the result we want. As a side note, I think it is much more common for the developer to define element sizes (either with constraints or other relative methods), particularly with image views.